# p:fileupload, how to show preview div when set auto=true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" auto="true" />
```

following is set auto to true. preview panel is gone
 [image: auto to true]

following is set auto to false. preview panel is showing
[image: auto to false]

When set auto to true, **PrimeFaces** removed the preview div. Which caused unable to remove the uploaded file before saving. is there any workaround?
Set auto to true but still showing the preview panel with close img to remove uploaded the file.

Comment: The 'preview panel' with the 'cancle/close/remove' button is to remove/prevent images from being uploaded. And with `auto=true` the image is immediately uploaded so preventing it from being uploaded is not possible. This functionality is not for removing uploaded images. That is something you need to develop yourself in e.g. a datagrid/datatable/...

Comment: ok.. thanks. To solve this, i added a panel to display uploaded files and option to remove from there.

Comment: Please copy large parts of my comment and add the most relevant parts of your code solution both in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the comment above > The 'preview panel' with the 'cancle/close/remove' button is to remove/prevent images from being uploaded. And with auto=true the image is immediately uploaded so preventing it from being uploaded is not possible. This functionality is not for removing uploaded images. " by  Kukeltje.

clarify my misunderstanding of auto=true option. solution as followed:

- As file already uploaded, use backend bean to temporary hold and display the value without saving to actual path or database (in my case actual-path)

Backend bean methods:

```
List<UploadedFile> uploadedPhotoes = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    uploadedPhotoes.add(event.getFile());
}
public void removeUploadedPhoto(int index) {
    uploadedPhotoes.remove(index);
}

public String getImageContentsAsBase64(UploadedFile photo) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getContents());
}
```

on xhtml file:

```
<ui:repeat var="photo" value="#{biddingPlaceBean.uploadedPhotoes}" varStatus="loop" >
```

Comment: not sure why its not showing the html code. pasting it here. <ui:repeat var="photo" value="#{biddingPlaceBean.uploadedPhotoes}" varStatus="loop" >
<p:row>
  <p:column style="border:none;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,#{biddingPlaceBean.getImageContentsAsBase64(photo)}" width="100px" /></p:column>
  <p:column style="border:none;"><p:commandButton value="Remove" actionListener="#{biddingPlaceBean.removeUploadedPhoto(loop.index)}" update=":biddingPlaceForm:photo" /></p:column>
 </p:row>
</ui:repeat>

Comment: Your infentation of the code is not correct. Use 4 spaces ibn front of each line or the 'code' button

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the image using **base 64**, saving its respective value in a String. In such a way that when the image is loaded again, update its value and show its new value, in case you want to change the image for a new one.One approach may be the following, your xhtml:

```html
<h:panelGroup id="pnlImage" layout="block" styleClass="fl_container_24">      
 <h:panelGroup id="pnlImageFoto" styleClass="fl_prefix_4 fl_grid_4 fl_suffix_4"> 
 <h:graphicImage id="imagen" value="#{YourMb.Image}" 
 styleClass="ui-expanded-widget-horizontal"/>
    </h:panelGroup>                              
</h:panelGroup>
                    
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="fl_clear" />
<p:spacer height="4"/>
                    
<h:panelGroup id="FileImage" layout="block" styleClass="fl_container_24">      
 <p:fileUpload id="btnUpload"
  label="upload image"
        fileUploadListener="#{YourMb.uploadImage}" auto="true"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpg|JPG|JPEG|jpeg|png|PNG)$/" 
        styleClass="fl_prefix_4 fl_grid_4 fl_suffix_4" mode="advanced" update="pnlImage" skinSimple="true"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Your MB:

```js
public void uploadImage(FileUploadEvent event) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
            String nameImage = uploadedFile.getFileName();
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputstream());
            String tempImage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(nameImage);
            Image = Objects.isNull(extension) || extension.isEmpty() ? null: 
                    "data:image/" + extension.trim() + ";base64," + tempImage;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            image= null;            
            
        }
    }
```